# Implement an array using foreach in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've a several `li` elements which have as class : `multiselect_selected_profil`.

```
<li id="li60" class="multiselect_my_profil multiselect_selected_profil" data-id="60">
    <span class="multiselect_profil">C1</span>
</li>
```

I would like that for each `li` that has this specific class, I get its `data-id` and then put it into an array. At then end of the process I would like to have an array which contains all the ids.

Here is what I've tried :

```
$(".multiselect_selected_profil").each(function(){
    var iObjetId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    // ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look attached snippet.

```js
var dataid = [];  //Initialize the array variable


$(".multiselect_selected_profil").each(function(){
    var iObjetId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    dataid.push(iObjetId);    
});

alert(dataid);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="li60" class="multiselect_my_profil multiselect_selected_profil" data-id="60"><span class="multiselect_profil">C1</span></li>
<li id="li60" class="multiselect_my_profil multiselect_selected_profil" data-id="61"><span class="multiselect_profil">C2</span></li>
<li id="li60" class="multiselect_my_profil multiselect_selected_profil" data-id="62"><span class="multiselect_profil">C3</span></li>
<li id="li60" class="multiselect_my_profil multiselect_selected_profil" data-id="63"><span class="multiselect_profil">C4</span></li>
<li id="li60" class="multiselect_my_profil multiselect_selected_profil" data-id="64"><span class="multiselect_profil">C5</span></li>
```

Comment: What if that class is being added to the element after page load? I'm assuming it will be based on it's naming

Answer (score 2):

```
var ids = []
$(".multiselect_selected_profil").each(function(){
var iObjetId = $(this).attr('data-id');
ids.push(iObjetId);
}
```

Create an empty array and push ids

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map()` to create an array from a set of matched elements:

```
var arr = $(".multiselect_selected_profil").map(function() {
    return $(this).data('id');
}).get()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = [];

$(".multiselect_selected_profil").each(function(){
   if($(this)..hasClass( "specific_class_name" )){
     ids.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
   }
});
```

now you will get all ids those contains specific class

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be specifying the `data-id` right in the selector description and use `toArray()` function to retrieve all the elements contained in the `jQuery` set, as an array:

```
var arr = $(".multiselect_selected_profil[data-id]").toArray();
```